# cv error on image stacking using cv.hconcat

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to read an image and convert it to a different color space and split all it's individual components and display all four in the form of a tile as mentioned below :

[ Original , Component_1
Component_2, Component_3 ]

But, when I try to do it. I get this error:

```
  File "chromaKey.py", line 64, in <module>
    img_obj.colorSpaceComponents(option,path)
  File "chromaKey.py", line 31, in colorSpaceComponents
    img_2d_tile = cv.vconcat([cv.hconcat(img_list) for img_list in img_2d])
  File "chromaKey.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    img_2d_tile = cv.vconcat([cv.hconcat(img_list) for img_list in img_2d])
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_operations.cpp:67: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src[i].dims <= 2 && src[i].rows == src[0].rows && src[i].type() == src[0].type() in function 'cv::hconcat'
```

I've also checked the dimensions and they seem to be the same for all 4 images. I'm not sure why they won't stack properly.

Here's my code below:

```
# Importing Packages
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

class Image_Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def colorSpaceComponents(self,option,path):
        # reading images
        img_original = cv.imread(path)
        c1 = c2 = c3 = ''
        # Converting the images to different color-spaces and grey-scaling them
        if option == '-XYZ':
            img_converted = cv.cvtColor(img_original,cv.COLOR_BGR2XYZ)
            c1,c2,c3 = cv.split(img_converted)
        elif option == '-YCrCb':
            img_converted = cv.cvtColor(img_original,cv.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
            c1,c2,c3 = cv.split(img_converted)
        elif option == '-Lab':
            img_converted = cv.cvtColor(img_original,cv.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
            c1,c2,c3 = cv.split(img_converted)
        elif option == '-HSB':
            img_converted = cv.cvtColor(img_original,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            c1,c2,c3 = cv.split(img_converted)
        elif option == '-RGB':
            c1,c2,c3 = cv.split(img_original)

        # Structuring the images to tiles
        img_2d = [[img_original,c1],[c2,c3]]
        img_2d_tile = cv.vconcat([cv.hconcat(img_list) for img_list in img_2d])

        # Creating the windows
        cv.namedWindow("Stacked_Image", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv.resizeWindow("Stacked_Image", 1280, 720)

        # Displaying the result
        cv.imshow('Stacked_Image',img_2d_tile)
        cv.waitKey(0)

        # Destroying the windows
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Getting the arguments given to the program
    argument_one = sys.argv[1]
    argument_two = sys.argv[2]

    # Checking the first argument, to determine if it's task 1 or task 2
    task_flag = 0
    if('-' in argument_one):
        task_flag = 1
    else:
        task_flag = 2

    # Creating an object for the class Image_handler
    img_obj = Image_Handler()

    # Calling the function according to task flag
    if task_flag == 1:
        path = str(sys.argv[2])
        option = str(sys.argv[1])
        img_obj.colorSpaceComponents(option,path)
        print('Task 01 complete')
```

Thanks for your answers in advance. Also attaching an image of the desired result.
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: It seems you are trying to concatenate image of different types (one BGR image and three grayscale images). Try converting the individual components to BGR before concatenating.

Comment: Yes will adding an additional channel to the greyscale images work while preserving each pixel value?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I'm trying to concatenate images with different shapes, most particularly the original has 3 channels where the individual components c1, c2 and c3 are greyscale images so they only have a width and height in their shape so all we need to do is add a channel to the components using.

```
c1 = np.stack((c1,)*3, axis=-1)
c2 = np.stack((c2,)*3, axis=-1)
c3 = np.stack((c3,)*3, axis=-1)
```